# How do I encourage Pony to NOT use my layout when using Pony to send an email using a template

Tags: sinatra, erb, pony

I'm sending like this:

```
Pony.mail :to => 'me@mine.com.au',
        :from => 'me@mine.com.au',
        :subject => 'Howdy, Partna!',
        :body => erb(:email)
```

It's working really well, except the plain text email arrives full of the layout html

How do I tell it to not use the layout, just the email.erb template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
set :erb, :layout => false
body = erb (:_emailhtml )
Pony.mail :to => 'will@kindleman.com.au',
        :from => 'will@kindleman.com.au',
        :subject => 'Howdy, Partna!',            
        :html_body => body
```

Pony / ruby / sinatra didn't like putting the erb (:_emailhtml) direct into the options hash, and the layout file needed to be set before the erb method.

yay.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pony.mail :to => 'me@mine.com.au',
    :from => 'me@mine.com.au',
    :subject => 'Howdy, Partna!',
    :body => erb(:email, layout: false)
```